# vb.net get all attributes value using htmlagilitypack

Tags: vb.net, attributes, href, html-agility-pack

this is the html

```
<div id="catlist-listview" class="cat-listview cat-listbsize">  
 <ul>
  <li><a href="http://wantedlink1" rel="bookmark" title="sometitel1" class="sonra">title1</a></li>    
  <li><a href="http://wantedlink2" rel="bookmark" title="sometitel2" class="sonra">title2</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://wantedlink3" rel="bookmark" title="sometitel3" class="sonra">title3</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://wantedlink4" rel="bookmark" title="sometitel4" class="sonra">title4</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://wantedlink5" rel="bookmark" title="sometitel5" class="sonra">title5</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://wantedlink6" rel="bookmark" title="sometitel6" class="sonra">title6</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://wantedlink7" rel="bookmark" title="sometitel7" class="sonra">title7</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://wantedlink8" rel="bookmark" title="sometitel8" class="sonra">title8</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://wantedlink9" rel="bookmark" title="sometitel9" class="sonra">title9</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://wantedlink10 " rel="bookmark" title="sometitel10" class="sonra">title10</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

and my code is

```
dim htmldoc as new htmldocument
htmldoc.loadhtml(source)
for each link as htmlnode in htmldoc.document.selectnodes("//*[@id='catlist-listview']/ul")
textbox3.text = link.innerhtml
next
```

the output is

```
      <li><a href="http://wantedlink1" rel="bookmark" title="sometitel1" class="sonra">title1</a></li>    
      <li><a href="http://wantedlink2" rel="bookmark" title="sometitel2" class="sonra">title2</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://wantedlink3" rel="bookmark" title="sometitel3" class="sonra">title3</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://wantedlink4" rel="bookmark" title="sometitel4" class="sonra">title4</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://wantedlink5" rel="bookmark" title="sometitel5" class="sonra">title5</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://wantedlink6" rel="bookmark" title="sometitel6" class="sonra">title6</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://wantedlink7" rel="bookmark" title="sometitel7" class="sonra">title7</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://wantedlink8" rel="bookmark" title="sometitel8" class="sonra">title8</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://wantedlink9" rel="bookmark" title="sometitel9" class="sonra">title9</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://wantedlink10 " rel="bookmark" title="sometitel10" class="sonra">title10</a></li>
```

i want get all and only `http://wantedlink1` to `http://wantedlink10`
i try attributes("href") but i get only one link 
i want to list all the link like this :

```
http://wantedlink1 
http://wantedlink2 
http://wantedlink3 
.
. 
. 
http://wantedlink10
```

any help ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can change XPath for `SelectNodes()` to be selecting individual `<a>` elements instead of `<ul>`. Then from this point, it will be easy to iterate through the result and get `href` attribute one by one. Or you achieve the same using LINQ, like the following for example :

```
'select <a> elements'
Dim links = htmldoc.Document.SelectNodes("//*[@id='catlist-listview']/ul/li/a")
'project to IEnumerable of href attribute value'
Dim hrefs = links.Cast(Of HtmlNode)().Select(Function(x) x.GetAttributeValue("href", ""))
'join the `hrefs`, separated by newline, into one string'
textbox3.text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, hrefs)
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qK0ZpM)</kbd>**

Comment: @SnoopyOhoo right, was mixed up with C# syntax there. You're welcome, and thanks for the correction

Comment: can you tell me how to list the links in `listbox` instead of `textbox3`
i can list links with `listbox1.items.addrange(textbox3.lines)`
but i want it directly to `listbox1` and delete `textbox3`

Comment: `listbox1.items.addrange(hrefs)`